# I need to clone an Azure SQL Database, which will take it past the SQL Pool Max Data Size - will it automatically increase?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-elasticpool

I have an Azure SQL Elastic Pool with 24 databases. The pool size in the portal is given as:

- Used: 412 GB
- Allocated: 540 GB
- Max: 750 GB

One of the databases is around 300 GB and I need to take a copy of it to be worked on separately from the original database, which will stay in place.

It looks likely that the new database plus existing ones will exceed the Data Max Size of the pool, so do I need to allocate extra storage in advance or will it auto-grow when I create the database copy?

I've tried lots of researching to find a definitive answer to this, but most of the help I've read is referring to a single database rather than an elastic pool.

Comment: What is the number of DTUs you have given the elastic pool? Or have you opted for vCore pricing model?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find an answer but I shall just grow the pool manually in advance using the slider under Configure on the Elastic Pool blade